# How to remove logged user profile href link

Tags: admin-bar

I have a requirement and the requirement was, I need to remove some menu options from the front end WordPress admin bar after a user logged in. I have achieved almost all. Now I stuck up with the profile link. I need to display only admin bar and name of the user like Howdy "Ajay" (name of the user) and logout option only. The name of the user should not have any link. But the name of the user is having `sitename/wp-admin/profile.php`. So how can I remove this href link from the username. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code to remove other menu items from admin bar:

```
function remove_menuitems_from_admin_bar()
{
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('user-info');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('site-name');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('dashboard');
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_menuitems_from_admin_bar');
```

Comment: put some code that you tried or put the code that displays admin bar, so i can check and try to help.

Comment: I have updated my question, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
function remove_menuitems_from_admin_bar() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('user-info');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('site-name');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('dashboard');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('edit-profile', 'user-actions');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account');

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (!$user_id)
        return;

    $avatar = get_avatar($user_id, 26);       
    $howdy = sprintf(__('Howdy, %s'), '<span class="display-name">' . $current_user->display_name . '</span>');
    $class = empty($avatar) ? '' : 'with-avatar';

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
        'id' => 'my-account',
        'parent' => 'top-secondary',
        'title' => $howdy . $avatar,
        'meta' => array(
            'class' => $class,
        ),
    ));
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_menuitems_from_admin_bar');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, still I am getting profile link , no change :(

Comment: <a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://localhost/site_name/wp-admin/profile.php" title="My Account">Howdy, <span class="display-name">Ajay Babu</span></a> if you see in href still I am getting this , copied from inspect element

Comment: Strange, as i tried this code and works fine. are you sure that you replaced your function with above function in my answer?

Comment: hey ,some thing got missed from my side. Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that it helped you.